# Android: Options for DSP libraries

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, signal-processing

I'm looking for a fast DSP library for Android.  It looks as though using FFTW or some other native library with JNI may be my best option.  I've used JTransforms, and it *appears* to be competitive with DSP libraries for x86 and other platforms, but it's limited strictly to doing FFTs.

Acceptable answers include (and hopefully be backed up with something more than anecdotal evidence if possible):

- Confirm that a native solution with JNI is my best bet
- A suggestion for a fast Java non-JNI solution exists
- No good solution yet exists.

The target medium is image data.

Comment: Did you find anything that is GPU or HW optimized, similar to iOS libraries?

Comment: I wasn't developing for iOS.  My best suggestion is to find a survey of various FFT implementations that compare their performance.  I found a page some years ago (I don't have the URL anymore) that compared JTransforms, FFTW, and a number of other implementations, giving a very nice breakdown of the tests & results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for Java libraries rather than just Android libraries. Most algorithms I programmed on Android were either pure Java or sometimes JNI. You don't always notice the difference in performance between the two and it's hard to put my finger on what exact cases JNI works faster in. I believe most java libraries (if they're purely computational) should run just fine on an Android.

Comment: You ended up being correct.  I didn't want to admit that a pure java implementation could be competitive with a well-optimized C implementation, but the one I found was very hard to beat.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg what was "the one" you found? Could you link to it so others can explore it as an option?

Comment: oof.  I'm sorry I didn't state that in my comment.  I no longer have the code, but I searched through gmail and found a snippet with `import edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_2D;` in it.